# ASUS TUF DASH F15 NVIDIA RTX3060 Laptop

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

Good evening all of you,
I have been troubling with the following problem now for about 3 days.

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on that machine. Everything is running fine. No error during installation. But until I tried to install the Nvidia-Driver. The installation itself is looking good and no errors are visible. But as soon as I reboot to make all changes apply, the machine freezes in the purple screen during boot process.
Somehow that has to be related to the Nvidia-Drivers because I have rebootet the machine a lot of times before the installation of the Nvidia-Drivers. And I have reinstalled the machine a lot of times now. As soon as I install the Nvidia-Driver my machine stops booting.

Is that already a known issue? How can I fix that problem. I need the machine to run on ubuntu 18.04 with the Nvidia-Graphics card.

Thanks you

Comment: which nvidia  driver did you install? why not install 20.04?

Comment: I have used different way to try if it works out. 
First I used the command <sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall> when I was running into the problem for the first time I reinstalled my machine and used the additional driver in the software updater settings and choose the proprietary, tested (470 )driver per mouse click. After that would not work either I reinstalled the machine again and I downloaded the driver from the nvidia website itself as a .run file. Then I had the same problem.So I wait until I find a how to fix the problem before to reinstall the machine. I need 18.04 due to developing